# Filter Array of custom objects using NSPredicate in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsmutablearray, nspredicate

I have one array which contains dictionary of custom objects.I want to filter that array for search functionality in UITableView. Here is my code for single object Filtration using NSPredicate.

```
self.searchResultForName = [self.multiPracticeDetailsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    ObjectHolder *obj = (ObjectHolder*)evaluatedObject;
    return [obj.Name hasPrefix:searchText];
}]];
```

Using above code, I can search only for Name , but i want to search for both By Name and ID.Also search will be case insensitive. How can i do this in Objective-C?.Please Suggest any better way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you tried with `||` OR operator & `lowercaseString`.

```
self.searchResultForName = [self.multiPracticeDetailsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    ObjectHolder *obj = (ObjectHolder*)evaluatedObject;
    return [[obj.Name lowercaseString] hasPrefix:[searchText lowercaseString]] || [[obj.ID lowercaseString] hasPrefix:[searchText lowercaseString]] ;
}]];
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try filtering it like this, assuming your *ObjectId* property is NSInteger:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Name =[c] %@ OR ObjectId =[c] %ld", searchText, searchId];
NSArray *filteredArray = [self.multiPracticeDetailsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```